# How to fix SameSite issue on Spring Boot - Jhipster?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cookies, jhipster

I'm using Jhipster stack with Sring Boot as back-end and React as front-end. I'm using Cloudinary to host images.

The problem is whenever the page has `img` tag get `src` from Cloudinary, chrome show the warning about the SameSite issue.

```html
<img src={'https://res.cloudinary.com/...'} alt={'xxx'} />
```

```
Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests.
4 cookies
Name    Domain & Path
_mkto_trk   .cloudinary.com/
_gcl_au .cloudinary.com/
_ga .cloudinary.com/
_ga_NKMQJY2D2H  .cloudinary.com/
```

I tried to search on Google and Spring Boot documents, Jhipster documents, but I can't find the config for this stack.

Comment: it doesn't work, I think samesite and cors are different, I still got images from Cloudinary

Comment: You're right, sorry you should have a look at   `jhipster.security.content-security-policy` value in application.yml